# error migrating unsigned char* in 64-bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

Let's say I have this `NSData` that save using 32 bit, but now my users migrating and use 64 bit.

when I get back the `NSData` from my file, and read again, it read wrongly, since the bytes is different. any help would be appreciated :

```
-(IBAction) generate{   
    NSData *data = [[File sharedFile] getObject:@"token"];
    unsigned char *ch = (unsigned char*)[data bytes]; // I think this is went wrong, when the bytes now is different. 
    Token *d;
    d = d->resurrect(ch); // this read differently if the unsigned char is different size
    NSString* token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",d->generateToken()]; 
}
```

**UPDATE**

resurrect() is static library method,

```
static Device* resurrect(unsigned char* bdev);
```

Comment: are you saving a pointer to a file and expect it will be still valid when you'll read it back? that doesn't work even in 32bit, nor in any other addressing schema. You need to make a deep copy and read back that.

Comment: Size of a char is one. Always.

Comment: Show us the implementation of `resurrect`. By the way, `d->resurrect(...)` isn't really Obj-C. I am not sure what that is since `d` seems to not be initialized.

Comment: no, it's c++ syntax from static library